# Select filtered nested foreign key for a model to marshal in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have a questionnaire model (which named bottle) with related foreign key questions, and have answers model relate to question model.

```
class Bottle(BaseModel):
    b_name = db.Column(db.String(8))
    questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='bottle')
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)

class Question(BaseModel):
    q_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    q_index = db.Column(db.Integer())
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='question')
    q_bottle = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Bottle.id))
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)

class Answer(BaseModel):
    a_index = db.Column(db.Integer())
    a_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    a_score = db.Column(db.Integer())
    a_question = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Question.id))
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
```

In flask-restful I want response a questionnaire data to json, So I

```
answer_fields = {
    "id": fields.Integer,
    "a_name": fields.String,
    "a_score": fields.Integer,
    "a_index": fields.Integer
}

question_fields = {
    "id": fields.Integer,
    "q_name": fields.String,
    "q_index": fields.Integer,
    "answers": fields.Nested(answer_fields)
}

bottle_fields = {
    "questions": fields.Nested(question_fields),
    "b_name": fields.String,

}

single_bottle_fields = {
    "data": fields.Nested(bottle_fields),
    "status": fields.Integer,
    "msg": fields.String,
    "request_time": fields.String
}


class BottleResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(single_bottle_fields)
    def get(self, id):
        bottle = Bottle.query.get(id)
        data = {
            "status": 201,
            "msg": "Well Done!",
            "data": bottle,
            "request_time": request_time
        }
        return data
```

I want to get the bottle with questions and theirs answers which is_deleted is false.

but the result of marshal_with will return all foreign keys for the model and its nested model too. So I will get a bottle which have all related questions. I only want the questions which is_deleted == false and their answers which is_deleted == false, and since the answers are nested to questions so maybe I can't just write a def to rewrite question's answer attribute.

How can I get a bottle which only has questions which theirs is_deleted is false and questions' answers which theirs is_deleted is false too?

Thank you!

Comment: I have already found the way to solve this.
The key is sqlalchemy!
you can create attribute for question:
```
ok_questions = db.relationship("Question",
                                  primaryjoin="and_(Bottle.id==Question.q_bottle, "
                                              "Question.is_deleted!=1)")
```
and then you can just marshal the ok_questions instead questions in bottle_fields. Because you will get a selective foreign key for the model.